# Error : no exception was thrown when one is expected

Tags: c++, exception

I have created an exception :OutOfRangeException

```
char& Chaine::operator[](int index){

    try{
        if((index < 0)){
            throw OutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
    catch(const Chaine::OutOfRangeException &e){
        cerr<<"Erreur"<<endl;   
    }

    return tab[index];
}
```

When i want to test it :

```
TEST_CASE("exceptions") {
  Chaine s(10);

  REQUIRE_THROWS_AS( s[-1] == 0, Chaine::OutOfRangeException);

}
```

It gives me an erro which says : no exception was thrown when one was expected.
How is this possible ?

Comment: Your operator overload doesn't rethrow the exception, so it never gets "seen" outside of the function

Comment: So how do I fix it?

Comment: don't catch the exception or when you do, call `throw` to rethrow it

Comment: But the operator is inside the class Chaine, so how can I make it visible outside the function?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the test case to test whether there is an exception of type `Chaine::OutOfRangeException` thrown that it can catch when executing the expression `s[-1] == 0`.

You *do* throw an exception of that type with `throw OutOfRangeException();`, but you catch it in the `operator[]` itself, with `catch(const Chaine::OutOfRangeException &e)`.

Therefore this `throw` never reaches outside the `s[-1] == 0` statement and the test doesn't see it.

If you expect the exception to reach the outside of the function it is thrown in, either remove the `try`/`catch` block or rethrow the exception:

```
catch(const Chaine::OutOfRangeException &e){
    cerr<<"Erreur"<<endl;
    throw; 
}
```

I would go with the former, because I don't think the operator should be responsible for notifying the user of the error. The caller of the function can decide for themselves whether they want to print an error message when they catch the exception. Or if they don't catch the exception anywhere, the program will terminate with an error message contained in the `OutOfRangeException` object.

Even if the operator overload is responsible for printing to `cerr`, it can do so simply in the `if`, it does not need to catch and rethrow the 
exception:

```
char& Chaine::operator[](int index){

    if(index < 0){
        cerr<<"Erreur"<<endl;   
        throw OutOfRangeException(); 
    }

    return tab[index];
}
```

Comment: @AliceLangertton Pure "thank you" comments are not very welcome here. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for what you can do instead to thank a user for their answer (although you are not compelled to do anything at all)